# Resign keyboard when leaving textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, textfield

Hey, I have created a textfield within two custom cells. One textfield shows the standard keyboard and the other the shows a pickerview when entered. The problem I have is when I move from the keyboard to pickerview textfield without clicking the "return" button on the keyboard, the keyboard doesn't resign. However when I do it using the "return" the keyboard resigns. Am using:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)myTextField{
 [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

and can't work out why this isn't working.

Thanks,
   William

Answer (score 2):

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if(textField == pickertextfield)
    {
        [textfield1 resignFirstResponder];
        [pickertextfield resignFirstResponder];

    }
return YES;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..

Answer (score 1):

Does your view controller adopt `<UITextFieldDelegate>`? Is it hooked up as the delegate of your text fields?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It does implement the delegate and it is hooked up because it enters the above "textFieldDidEndEditing" method.For some reason it just doesn't actually resign it when I move directly from one textfield to another without dismissing the keyboard using the "return" key.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `[self.view endEditing:YES];` before showing the pickerview and see it it helps.